# How to select element by classpath (SELENIUM, PYTHON)

Tags: python, css, selenium

I Trying select this path but not works,

```
chrome_options = Options()
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  # interactive
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('https://www.santander.com.br/emprestimo/login')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#cpf.my-4.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.dss-form-field__input.ng-touched').send_keys(cpf)
```

Tried,
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#cpf.my-4.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.dss-form-field__input.ng-touched').send_keys(cpf)
//div[contains(@class, "dss-form-field dss-form-field--right-icon")]

Answer (score 0):

The field you are trying to select is inside Shadow DOM.  Such elements are quite straightforward to access using Chrome and Selenium 4:

```
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "pdc-juc-root")
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
input = shadow_root.find_element(By.ID, "cpf")
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(input).click().send_keys("123456789").perform()
# delay before closing so can see that it works!
time.sleep(3)
```